# Can we have pic of Kaali mata in our home?

Tags: kali

Recently i got love/faith in `Adi Shakti` specially in form of `Kaali Maa` i want to pooja and place pic of kaali maa in home but i am scared form nature of Kaali maa is `Prachand` my parents are also making me scare of that please some can put some words on this should i do in our home

I already watched some videos on youtube but my doubts are not clear. i still feel in my heart

i am really very much trouble on this

Comment: You can see the answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20597/4732. Other than Chinnamasta and Dhumavati other Goddess forms can be kept. But always better to consult a Purohit from your place. Regional traditions and beliefs are also important.

Comment: if kept in the home you should do some worship to the image everyday (it can be a simple offering), it should not be hung as a decoration.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda in home any specific direction where i can place picture for worship?

Comment: @Rickross in home any specific direction where i can place picture for worship?

Comment: You should place in the north eastern corner of the room or the eastern corner. Place an elevated altar and place the image on it. You can also spread red cloth on the altar before placing the image. @VipanKumar

Comment: Thanks @Rickross I did the same as i research and books

Comment: Good to know :) @VipanKumar